# Question on Angular Acceleration and Velocity

Tags: rotational-kinematics

suppose, we have a body with an angular velocity, $$\vec \omega=(at,b,0)$$ where $a,b$  are constants. so the angular acceleration is clearly, $$\dot{\vec{\omega}}=(a,0,0) $$

but my question is if the body is rotating as the $\vec \omega$ vector says then it must have at  least two components of angular acceleration, no ? for as the $b\hat y$ component itself rotates ( because of the $at\hat x$ component) it cannot be a constant vector however constant in magnitude. what am I missing here ? can you propose a way to actually simulate this motion (maybe Matlab) ?

Comment: I don't understand why you say *"then it must have at least two components of angular acceleration"*.

Comment: It has an angular acceleration in the xy plane but since it's moving at a constant angular velocity on the xz plane it does not accelerate. Your question isn't very clear though

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the components of $\omega$ are w.r.t. the world coordinate system and do not follow the body around. Are are thinking that $\hat{y}$ is rotating, but it is not.

To go from Euler rotations to angular velocity you need something like this

$$ \begin{align} 
  E & = {\rm Rot}(\hat{k},\varphi){\rm Rot}(\hat{j},\psi) {\rm Rot}(\hat{i},\theta) \\
  \vec{\omega} &= \hat{k} \dot{\varphi} + {\rm Rot}(\hat{k},\varphi) \hat{j} \dot\psi + {\rm Rot}(\hat{k},\varphi){\rm Rot}(\hat{j},\psi) \hat{i} \dot\theta \\
 & = \begin{pmatrix} 
   \dot\theta \cos\varphi\cos\psi-\dot\psi\sin\varphi \\
   \dot\theta\cos\psi\sin\theta+\dot\psi\cos\theta \\
   \dot\varphi-\dot\theta \sin\psi
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align} $$

The problem is that to make this match the prescribed $\vec{\omega}$ you actually need rotations about all three euler angles

$$\begin{align} 
  \dot{\varphi} &= \tan\psi \;\frac{b \sin\varphi+a t \cos\theta}{\cos(\varphi-\theta)} \\
  \dot{\psi} & = \frac{b\cos\varphi - a t \sin\theta}{\cos(\varphi-\theta)} \\
  \dot{\theta} & = \frac{b \sin\varphi+a t \cos\theta}{\cos\psi \cos(\varphi-\theta)}
\end{align} $$

In the end, such "simple" contrived angular velocity ends up being in reality a complex orchestration of 3 mutually perpendicular rotations (euler angles).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little program in VPython to display the motion.  This code creates a spinning red box with a white arrow pointing in the direction of the angular velocity.

```
from visual import *

spinner = box(length=.5, height=.5, width=.5, color=color.red)
t=0.0
a=0.72
b=3.9

spinner.angvelocity = vector(a*t,b,0)
spin=arrow(axis=spinner.angvelocity)

dt = 0.001
while 1:
    rate(100)
    spinner.rotate(angle=pi*mag(spinner.angvelocity)*dt, axis=spinner.angvelocity, origin=(0,0,0))

    t=t+dt
    spinner.angvelocity = vector(a*t,b,0)
    spin.axis=spinner.angvelocity/mag(spinner.angvelocity)
```

The motion looks like what I expected when the initial spin rate isn't too small -- the box starts out spinning around a vertical axis, and that axis gradually leans to the right as the rate of spin increases.  When b is smaller, then the body axes don't align with the spin arrow, and this makes me wonder whether I'm doing things quite right.  It's interesting at any rate...

Please note I drew the axis arrow of fixed length to show the spin axis. It isn't displaying the angular velocity vector, which is lengthening as the motion proceeds.  If you want to display the angular velocity vector just delete "/mag(spinner.angvelocity)" from the last line of the program.

If I can manage to learn how to capture the VPython animation and post it here I'll try to accomplish that. You can install VPython yourself by starting at [vpython.org](http://vpython.org/) and have fun playing with it.  I've greatly enjoyed using it for physics animations over the years.

Here's an animation with a=1.9, 
b=0.8.
[image: spinner 2d a=1.9, b=0.8]